# Data Binding Issue in Win8.1 with Caliburn

Tags: c#, windows-8, binding, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I am having a bit of a problem updating a textbox after parsing a users input.
I am using the caliburn micro framework in windows 8.1 store app.

My properties are laid out as follows:

```
private string mass = "0";
    public string Mass
    {
        get { 
            return mass;
        }
        set
        {
            if (mass != value)
            {
                mass = value.ParseUserInput();
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Mass);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Result);
            }
        }
    }
```

with

```
 public static string ParseUserInput(this string value)
    {
        double result;
        double.TryParse(value, out result);
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

The problem I have is that when I enter a valid input e.g. "001.0" I would expect the textbox to update to reflect this by displaying "1" (mass is confirmed to change to "1") however it remains at "001.0"

If I put the NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Mass); statement in code that is called later then the text box updates as expected so I know that the binding is working two ways.
In addition the code works perfectly in my wpf project.

Anybody have some ideas ( a threading issue ?)

OK, I changed the line to :

```
new System.Action(() => base.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Mass)).BeginOnUIThread();
```

and this behaves as expected, any ideas why I have to do this as I believe it shouldn't be necessary, should it?

Many thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in the binding infrastructure of WinRT. My guess is that binding is ignoring your property changed notification for mass because it feels it's the one that told you it had changed.

By dispatching the change on to the UI thread you may be delaying the notification enough such that the binding doesn't think it triggered the notification.

Not a solution but it may explain why the code is needed.